# How can I create an admin that can add users in firebase?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I'm building an app that manages students' data for teachers?. The teacher needs to be able to register an account then be able to add multiple students to firebase auth. The students must only then sign in. How can I do this in firebase?.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. Make sure you give complete details on how you expect your app to work and any code that you may have tried. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Given there's an accepted answer, which is quite good, the bottom line is you can't do this directly via the client SDK's. The reason is that once a user authenticates and then creates another firebase user, it un-authenticates the first user and then authenticates the created user. So, you will need to leverage the Admin SDK to really do this per the answer. There are a couple of workarounds as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Firebase Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to assign a 'teacher' claim so you can differentiate between teachers and students. Thereafter you after you can [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to create a new student accounts.

In the cloud function, you can verify if the user calling the function is a teacher.

```
// Creates a new student account
exports.addStudent = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  //Getting data passed from frontend
  const {name, email, password, ...rest} = data;
  
  //Checking if the caller of function is a teacher
  if (!context.auth.token.teacher) return "You are not a teacher!";
  
  //Creating a new user account
  return admin
  .auth()
  .createUser({
    email,
    password: 'secretPassword',
    displayName: name,
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
    return userRecord.uid;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
    return "An error occured"
  });
});
```

Now it's upto you how you are going to create a teacher account. You can directly create it in a the Firebase console and write a one time function to add the teacher claim to them.

```
export.addTeacherClaim = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const {uid} = data;
  return admin
  .auth()
  .setCustomUserClaims(uid, { teacher: true })
  .then(() => {
    // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
    // next time a new one is issued.
    return true;
  });
})
```

You can call the functions from your React app like this:

```
const addStudent = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addStudent');
addMessage({ email: "name@domain.tld", name: "StudentName", password: "Password" })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    const newUserUid = result.data;
  });
```

Comment: Do you know another way I can do this without using cloud functions?. I couldn't use cloud functions because I currently don't have a credited.

Comment: @twfm_11 you would need some sort of secure environment, cloud functions or your own server. Only Admin SDK (which uses service account) can update Claims so you can't share the credentials as well. Without that you would have to manually update the claims or so.

Comment: "Do you know another way I can do this without using cloud functions?" Yes, you could work out a solution by declaring the roles in Firestore documents, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access) but note that without usinf the Admin SD a user will not be able to create another user. So the non-admin users should first create their account (e.g. with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`) and then the Admin should declare their roles in Firestore.

Comment: (continued) Don't forget to protect the collections/docs holding the roles: only the Admin should have write access. In conclusion, this approach is a bit more complex to implement compare to the Cloud Functions based approach but it is possible.